# Actionscript Socket Events not firing?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, networking

I'm writing a SWF that I'd like to communicate with a Java process via Sockets. This is usually quite easy with standard Sockets, but for some reason the events described in the Socket documentation aren't firing when all signs say they should be.

On the Java side, I've set up a [ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) that's listening on port 8080. Using netcat I've confirmed it works as designed.

On the Flash side, however, I'm setting up [per the examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#includeExamplesSummary) in the docs:

```
public function connectToPort(port : int):void
{   
    m_socket = new Socket();

    addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
    addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
    addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);
    addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
    addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);

    m_socket.connect("localhost", port);

    // trace() doens't work for the command-line :(
    m_debug.text = "Called connect!";
}
```

When I run the resulting SWF, all I get is "Called connect!" on the stage, and *none of the events ever fire*. Even more strangely, when I investigate the communication from the ServerSocket on the Java end, it receives and accepts a connection. When I close the SWF the code calling my Server completes as normal -- meaning it was hanging on a connection made with my SWF.

I'm left with a few questions...

- With the exception of the event handlers, this is the end of control for my code (after the connection is established, we just wait for events and render them appropriately).  Could the entire program be "terminating," and I'm just misunderstood about the Runtime model?
- Are there visibilty/naming requirements for the callbacks for them to be called? They're all public, but could it be that the Runtime isn't seeing them?
- Are there any gotchas with AS3 Socket programming? I kept thinking this was an issue of sandboxing, etc., but the SECURITY_ERROR didn't fire either...

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent most of my day on this and I'm very frustrated that I can't get basic socket communication to work :-/

Comment: If it helps, I'm doing most of my debugging in the Flash Debug Standalone Player.  When I run from the browser, the Java side doesn't receive the connection...

Comment: No, your program should not terminate here, it should just quietly wait for events.

No, there are no special naming requirements.

There should be a security error if the socket server doesn't serve up a policy file response unless the SWF is trusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the event listeners to the "this" object, not the socket.

try this:

```
m_socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
m_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
m_socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);
m_socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
m_socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
```

And you should start seeing socket events.

Answer (score 0):

These lines will add the event listeners to `this`, not `m_socket`

```
addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);
addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
```

To add them to `m_socket` use

```
with(m_socket) {
    addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
    addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
    addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);
    addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
    addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
}
```